# SQL dynamic unpivot table as function

Tags: sql

I currently have a query which I am using to unpivot an existing table.

Some background information on the table - each year a new column is added to the table to indicate the $ values for a project ID for that year. With every column added one will be dropped. All these columns are prefixed with 'YR_' followed by the new year. There are constantly 20 'YR_' columns.

I am required to unpivot the 'YR_' columns so that they appear as per below, allowing me to utilize the information easier for several reports -

Before unpivot -

```
ProjectID    YR_16   YR_17   YR_18   YR_19   YR_20
10           0       100     20      25      100
```

After unpivot -

```
ProjectID    YR      Value
10           YR_16   0
10           YR_17   100
10           YR_18   20
10           YR_19   25
10           YR_20   100
```

Below is the query I am using to create the unpivot table, which will dynamically pick up columns as they are added/dropped

```
declare @query as NVARCHAR(max);
Declare @cols as NVARCHAR(250) = STUFF((
Select distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Column_Name)
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'F1BWK_PLM_CAPEX'
And COLUMN_NAME like 'YR_%'
For XML Path(''), type)
.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
,1,1,'');

Select @query = 'With Unpivoted as 
(

Select * from F1BWK_PLM_CAPEX U

Unpivot (
Val
For Yr in (' + @cols + ')
)
As UnpivotTable 
)

Select U.*

From Unpivoted U
inner join [dbo].[F1_SYPAR_CTL] CTL
on CTL.value = U.WS_VERS
and CTL.PARAM_NAME like ''MBRC_CURR_PLM_BUDVER''
inner join [dbo].[F1_SYPAR_CTL] CTL2
on CTL2.value = U.WS_NAME
and CTL2.PARAM_NAME like ''MBRC_CURR_PLM_BUDWSH''';

Exec(@query);
```

I am having issues in turning this query into a function so that I can call upon it and save it in SQL Server so that other members of my team can use it when they require it.

This is my first time using unpivot tables and creating functions. Open to suggestions on changing my dynamic unpivot query to best suits my needs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Assuming this is SQL Server, then you can't have dynamic sql in functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server you are not allowed to have dynamic SQL in functions.

You can create an SP that will return a record set generated using your code above.

UPDATE:

For the sake of completeness:
You can also call the above SP using ([OPENQUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql)) which would allow you to join to other tables without having to save to a temp table first but IMO it is an ugly way do this.

END UPDATE:

Another way is to create a VIEW that would un-pivot this table and create an SP that would regenerate this view after the process that adds a new column is completed e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE F1BWK_PLM_CAPEX( Val INT, Yr_17 INT, Yr_18 INT )
INSERT INTO F1BWK_PLM_CAPEX
SELECT 1, 10, 12

CREATE VIEW F1BWK_PLM_CAPEX_UNPIVOTED
AS
    SELECT *
    FROM F1BWK_PLM_CAPEX AS U
    UNPIVOT (
        Val2 FOR Yr IN (Yr_17, Yr_18)
    )
    AS UnpivotTable;

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Create_F1BWK_PLM_CAPEX_UNPIVOTED
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @query as NVARCHAR(max);
    DECLARE @cols as NVARCHAR(250) =
        STUFF((
            SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME( Column_Name )
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'F1BWK_PLM_CAPEX'
                AND COLUMN_NAME like 'YR_%'
            For XML Path(''), type)
            .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)' )
        ,1,1,'');

    SELECT @query = '
    ALTER VIEW F1BWK_PLM_CAPEX_UNPIVOTED
    AS
        SELECT *
        FROM F1BWK_PLM_CAPEX AS U
        UNPIVOT (
            Val2 FOR Yr IN ( ' + @cols + ' )
        )
        AS UnpivotTable 
    ';

    EXEC(@query);
RETURN;
```

Now your query would become this:

```
SELECT *
FROM F1BWK_PLM_CAPEX_UNPIVOTED AS U
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[F1_SYPAR_CTL] AS CTL
        ON CTL.value = U.WS_VERS and CTL.PARAM_NAME = 'MBRC_CURR_PLM_BUDVER'
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[F1_SYPAR_CTL] AS CTL2
        ON CTL2.value = U.WS_NAME AND CTL2.PARAM_NAME = 'MBRC_CURR_PLM_BUDWSH'
```

At the end of the year a process runs that adds a new column:

```
ALTER TABLE F1BWK_PLM_CAPEX
    ADD Yr_19 INT NOT NULL DEFAULT( 10 )
```

This process needs to run this SP to regenerate the view:

```
EXEC Create_F1BWK_PLM_CAPEX_UNPIVOTED
```

**Notes:**

- I have replaced `LIKE` with `=` as your query matches on a full value. Only use `LIKE` when you need to specify wild cards.
- I have also fixed a syntax error by changing Val to Val2 in the `UNPIVOT` query

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain this and offering a very detailed explanation.

This worked a treat and has saved me a lot of time and heart ache.

I am still quite relatively new to SQL Server, and still learning the 'proper way' of doing things

I have defiantly taken your notes on board.

Comment: @R.Ayres - one more thing. Remember to add a large comment to the view along the lines of "This view is auto generated by Create_F1BWK_PLM_CAPEX_UNPIVOTED. Any changes made directly on the view will be lost.